API Gateway CORS works for GET method but not POST method
I have an API gateway endpoint   (https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage). It integrates with a lambda function. There are three methods (GET,POST,OPTIONS). CORS is enabled in the gateway and the lambda returns the necessary headers.
The GET method was only created for CORS testing. It works. However when it is posted I get a CORS error. This seems impossible. CORS is enabled in the API gateway at the resource level.
The error is :

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

The general info is:

Request URL:
https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
400 Bad Request
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

The request header:

Request URL:
https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage
Request Method:
POST
Status Code:
400 Bad Request
Referrer Policy:
strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Postman works... But the code (axios) doesn't.
Any ideas?? Thanks in advance.

Further info... the URL is posted from the JavaScript (vue, axios) as follows:   await this.$http.post("https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage",data,config).then(response =>

What CORS error? You haven't included the error message in your question; difficult to help you without it. My tip is this: in your browser's Network tab, inspect the Access-Control-Request-Headers header of the preflight request; for things to work, all the values listed there must also be listed in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header.

The error is :          Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://mhw8mm294k.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/saveImage' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Please add that error message to your question, not in comments. And what about my tip about Access-Control-Request-Headers?

Thanks with your help so far.... I added information to the original question regarding the request  header for the post.

No, read my earlier comment more closely.

Access-Control-Request-Headers is not present in the request... I added it to the response headers... I am sorry, I seem to be lost with your answers. If you could please answer in a different way

In the AWS API Gateway, when you enable CORS, the Access-Control-Request-Headers is set with a list of :    Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token  . I removed all but the Content-Type and redeployed.. The error is still present

Access-Control-Request-Headers != Access-Control-Allow-Headers

Added Access-Control-Allow-Headers to response, it still doesn't work.
